# Accessing Child class properties from parent class in drools

Tags: java, drools

I have a parent class Vehicle() passed in drools xls file how can I access the properties of the child class Car()?

I've tried casting it but it drools doesn't recognize the method cast

```
(Car.cast(vehicle)).isManual()
```

**Edit by laune** from OP's comment:
    The drools version I'm using is 4.0.7

```
import workspace.sampleproj.domain.* 
function boolean checkIfCarManual(Vehicle vehicle){
    if (vehicle.isCar() == true){ 
        if((Car.cast(vehicle).isManual() == true){ 
            return true;
        } else {
            return false; 
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the context where you use this? LHS - RHS - ?

Comment: Hi laune, I'm using this in the function call

Comment: Of what? And where? - You sure need a squeeze to get the juice flowing... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drools cannot recognize what cannot be recognized.

If your class `Car` has a static method `cast(Vehicle v)`, it should be recognized. (If there is no such method, you'll get an error.)

```
class Car extends Vehicle {
    public static Car cast( Vehicle v ){ return (Car)v; }
    ...
}
```

Perhaps you tried to use the `cast` method of `java.lang.Class`? If so, you'll have to write

```
(Car.class.cast(vehicle)).isManual()
```

**Later** And there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to use a straightforward cast:

```
function boolean checkIfCarManual(Vehicle vehicle){
    return vehicle.isCar() && ((Car)vehicle).isManual();
}
```

Comment: Hi Laune, Sorry I'm not quite familiar with drools so I can't explain myself clearly. Yes i've used the java.lang.Class but drools doesn't recognized it. Unfortunately, I can only change the drools xls and not the car domain. Is there other way to do this in the xls only? Thank you

Comment: Well, what *did* you *really* write while trying to call the `cast` method of `java.lang.Class`? And how did you use it in the xls?? Which Drools version??? Did you read my answer????

Comment: Apologies, Here's the function I'm trying to implement basically it checks if the vehicle obj is a car and if it is manual transmission. The drools version I'm using is 4.0.7. Unfortunately, I can't use your answer as I can only change the xls and not the domain.


`import workspace.sampleproj.domain.*

function boolean checkIfCarManual(Vehicle vehicle){
 if (vehicle.isCar() == true){
  if((Car.cast(vehicle).isManual() == true){
   return true;
  }

  else{
   return false;
  }
 }else{
      return false;
 }
}`

Comment: I've tried the '(Car.class.cast(vehicle)).isManual()' and its still can't recognize the method isManual() as the obj is still vehicle instead of car

Comment: The DRL parser is close to, but not matching, a Java parser. But there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to use a straightforward cast.

Comment: **Don't put code in comments - edit your question to provide more information.**

Comment: All good now. I use (Car) vehicle instead. Thanks and apologies I'm new here